# Agregar Marker en ViewMAp dentro de un Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, recyclerview

Bueno Intento colocar un marker en un mapa dentro de un Recyclerview aqui esta mi adapter.

public class Multas_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{

```
ArrayList<recycle_Multas_Adapter> listas_Informacion;


public Multas_Adapter(ArrayList<recycle_Multas_Adapter> listas_Informacion) {
    this.listas_Informacion = listas_Informacion;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.multas_generadas,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int i) {
    holder.nombre.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getNombre());
    holder.direccion.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDireccion());
    holder.multa.setText(listas_Informacion.get(i).getDato());
    holder.lt=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt();
    holder.lg=listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg();
    LatLng Lugar = new LatLng(listas_Informacion.get(i).getLt(),listas_Informacion.get(i).getLg());

    holder.mapCurrent.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Lugar).title("Ubicación actual"));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listas_Informacion.size();
}


public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolderDatos holder)
{
    // Cleanup MapView here?
    if (holder.mapCurrent != null)
    {
        holder.mapCurrent.clear();
        holder.mapCurrent.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    }
}

public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    TextView multa,direccion,nombre,ubi;
    double lt,lg;
    GoogleMap mapCurrent;
    MapView map;
    public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ubi=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ubi);
        map=(MapView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.map_card);
        multa=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.multa);
        direccion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.direccion);
        nombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        if (map != null)
        {
            map.onCreate(null);
            map.onResume();
            map.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


         mapCurrent = googleMap;
        }
    }
}
```

El mapa si se muestra en mi recyclerview pero no se como agregar el marker me salta este error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
        at mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.ui.Multas_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Multas_Adapter.java:56)
        at mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.ui.Multas_Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Multas_Adapter.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando cargas un mapa es importante saber que cuando se instancia el mapa y esta listo para mostrarse y agregar información esto se realiza en el método  [**onMapReady** (GoogleMap googleMap)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback.html#onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)).
ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Agrega marcador en Sydney, Australia,
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marcador en Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Se implementa el marker aqui.

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
Map = googleMap;
LatLng Centro = new LatLng(dos, uno);
Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Centro).title("Ubicación actual"));
Map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Centro));
Map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dos,uno), 17.0f));
```

}